# Уникальные профили пользователей

Tags: php

Надо, чтобы каждый profile.php был уникальным. Т.е., чтобы profile.php?id1 был с информацией пользователя под этим id. А другой profile.php уже был уникален под информацию другого пользователя. Но если вручную перейти с пользователя, допустим, id2, на страницу profile.php?id4, то этот пользователь не на своей странице увидит только свою информацию. Подскажите, что к чему. Код небольшой, но может пригодиться в разъяснении ответа:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    session_start();
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('proba');
    function redirect($url) {
        if(!$url) {
            $url =  'index.php';        
        }
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
    if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
        redirect('index.php');
    }
    $_SESSION['name'];
    $login = $_SESSION['name'];
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM game WHERE login='$login'") or die(mysql_error());
    echo $_SESSION['name'];
?>
```

Comment: Похоже, что для отображения данных Вы используете текущее имя пользователя (это уже подозрительно), а нужно использовать id, который пришел в запросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы делаете выборку данных из базы, используя имя пользователя из переменной `$login`, значения которой Вы получаете из сессии (`$_SESSION['name']`).
Пользователь логинится, у него в сессии сохраняется его имя в ключе `name`, и это значение не меняется от запроса к запросу, не смотря на передаваемые через `GET` параметры.

1) Идентификатор нужно передавать не так `profile.php?id1`, а `profile.php?id=1`.

2) Выборку нужно делать по идентификатору, а не по имени.

Код `profile.php` нужно изменить:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
session_start();
mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('proba');
function redirect($url) {
    if(!$url) {
        $url =  'index.php';        
    }
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
if(!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    redirect('index.php');
}
$id = $_GET['id']; // получаем переданный в запросе идентификатор
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM game WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Соответственно, запрос должен выглядеть так: `.../profile.php?id=123`.

Советую потратить хотя бы один вечер на то, чтобы пройти хоть какой-то курс видеоуроков по любому из популярных PHP фреймворков. Просто посмотрите как грамотно организововать свое приложение, если не захотите писать на фреймворке, а заодно узнаете много полезного.